# rospy logging configuration

Tags: ros, python, rosout, rospy, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rospy docs mention that from Diamondback on, rospy uses Python's logging library and configuration format.  Two questions about this:

- The link in the docs is broken.  Is there an example on the wiki about how to use this?
- How do the Python handlers interact with the publication of log messages on /rosout?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10269/rospy-logging-configuration/) by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1479 on 2011-06-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The python logging documentation is here:

http://docs.python.org/lib/module-logging.html

Admittedly, it is pretty difficult documentation to wade through and is part of the reason why I want to move away from the logging module.

The logging configuration file does not interact with log messages on /rosout. The /rosout log level can be overridden in the rospy.init_node call.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhaskara](https://answers.ros.org/users/95/bhaskara/) on 2011-06-20**:
Right, in particular, the linking text says "this is how your configuration file should look", but the documentation doesn't actually describe the config file format.  Python's logging looks pretty flexible actually, and I think it would be a good solution if 1) there was an example ros-specific configuration file in the wiki docs; 2) there was a unified way of controlling what's printed on the console/what's sent to rosout (i.e., by adding a subclass of logging.Handler).  Overriding things in rospy.init_node is not fine-grained, and it also means the user has to edit a (often version controlled or read-only) source file rather than changing a local config file (or eventually, maybe using a tool such as rxloggerlevel).  My 2c :)